# Docusign DEMO account authentication using REST API not working

Tags: php, api, rest, authentication, docusignapi

I am new to Docusign. I have a developer account and tryging to use REST API with PHP to establish connection with the API but i have stumble across and error, the Error is calling webservice and status is 0. Below is my code:

```
$username = "xxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxx";
$integrator_key = "xxxxxxx";

// construct the authentication header:
$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";


$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
//echo $status;
if ( $status != 200 ) {
echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
$baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Hopefully the `$username`, `$password`, and `$integrator_key` values are **not** the real production values; if so, you should change them, as they will be publicly visible/usable by anyone.

Comment: The code your are running is so common my first thoughts are that you are behind a firewall or other security software is stopping your request from getting out.  Can you confirm if either?  One good way to verify would be to go into your account preferences (I think under privacy) and enable Request Logging, then make your request through code and check your logs and see if anything came through...

Comment: Have you tried using your credentials via the API explorer? http://iodocs.docusign.com/

Comment: @Ergin when you say "go into your account preferences (I think under privacy) and enable Request Logging" are you referring to my account preferences within my DocuSign account?

Comment: @mikebz i have tested my credential via the API explorer, i believe there is no issues with my credential as it return the following results:
{
  "loginAccounts": [
    {
      "name": "XXXX",
      "accountId": "XXXX",
      "baseUrl": "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/XXXX",
      "isDefault": "true",
      "userName": "XXXX",
      "userId": "XXXX",
      "email": "XXXX",
      "siteDescription": ""
    }
  ]
}

Comment: @SamSit Yes that would be in your DocuSign account preferences.  Since your request works when you send through the API Explorer it once again points to the issue being security software or filtering happening on your (client) side.

Comment: @Ergin thank you for your advice i will look into my security settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by security software, firewall, or other network interference on your (client) side since your request works just fine when you send through the API Explorer.  I recommend tracing your request through your network to see where it is getting held up.